# Difference between Google OAuth2 Web Client flow & Desktop Client flow

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

[Google's OAuth2 for Desktop Client Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) says:

> Unlike with web clients, the OAuth 2.0 client secret (if used) is assumed not to be confidential.

This makes sense. However, I can't tell any difference between both flows that reflects this assumption: both flows yield an access token and a refresh token (even though the standard OAuth2 philosophy seems to be that you shouldn't hand out refresh tokens to non-confidential clients, and you should use the implicit grant flow instead).

Then what's the difference security-wise between both flows?

(Update: Maybe the latter always prompts for consent, even when the user already gave their consent?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274554/why-google-native-oauth2-flow-require-client-secret/7476709#7476709 nothing changed for years : /